# Core Text calculate letter frame in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-text, glyph

I need to calculate exact bounding box for every each character (glyph) in NSAttributedString (Core Text).
After putting together some code used to solve similar problems (Core Text selection, etc..), the result is quite good, but only few frames (red) are being calculated properly:

[image]

Most of the frames are misplaces either horizontally or vertically (by tiny bit). What is the cause of that? How can I perfect this code?:

```
-(void)recalculate{

    // get characters from NSString
    NSUInteger len = [_attributedString.string length];
    UniChar *characters = (UniChar *)malloc(sizeof(UniChar)*len);
    CFStringGetCharacters((__bridge CFStringRef)_attributedString.string, CFRangeMake(0, [_attributedString.string length]), characters);

    // allocate glyphs and bounding box arrays for holding the result
    // assuming that each character is only one glyph, which is wrong
    CGGlyph *glyphs = (CGGlyph *)malloc(sizeof(CGGlyph)*len);
    CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(_font, characters, glyphs, len);

    // get bounding boxes for glyphs
    CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(_font, kCTFontDefaultOrientation, glyphs, _characterFrames, len);
    free(characters); free(glyphs);

    // Measure how mush specec will be needed for this attributed string
    // So we can find minimun frame needed
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize s = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(_framesetter, rangeAll, NULL, CGSizeMake(W, MAXFLOAT), &fitRange);

    _frameRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
    CGPathRef framePath = CGPathCreateWithRect(_frameRect, NULL);
    _ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(_framesetter, rangeAll, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);


    // Get the lines in our frame
    NSArray* lines = (NSArray*)CTFrameGetLines(_ctFrame);
    _lineCount = [lines count];

    // Allocate memory to hold line frames information:
    if (_lineOrigins != NULL)free(_lineOrigins);
    _lineOrigins = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * _lineCount);

    if (_lineFrames != NULL)free(_lineFrames);
    _lineFrames = malloc(sizeof(CGRect) * _lineCount);

    // Get the origin point of each of the lines
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(_ctFrame, CFRangeMake(0, 0), _lineOrigins);

    // Solution borrowew from (but simplified):
    // https://github.com/twitter/twui/blob/master/lib/Support/CoreText%2BAdditions.m


    // Loop throught the lines
    for(CFIndex i = 0; i < _lineCount; ++i) {

        CTLineRef line = (__bridge CTLineRef)[lines objectAtIndex:i];

        CFRange lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line);
        CFIndex lineStartIndex = lineRange.location;
        CFIndex lineEndIndex = lineStartIndex + lineRange.length;

        CGPoint lineOrigin = _lineOrigins[i];
        CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
        CGFloat lineWidth = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading);


        // If we have more than 1 line, we want to find the real height of the line by measuring the distance between the current line and previous line. If it's only 1 line, then we'll guess the line's height.
        BOOL useRealHeight = i < _lineCount - 1;
        CGFloat neighborLineY = i > 0 ? _lineOrigins[i - 1].y : (_lineCount - 1 > i ? _lineOrigins[i + 1].y : 0.0f);
        CGFloat lineHeight = ceil(useRealHeight ? abs(neighborLineY - lineOrigin.y) : ascent + descent + leading);

        _lineFrames[i].origin = lineOrigin;
        _lineFrames[i].size = CGSizeMake(lineWidth, lineHeight);

        for (int ic = lineStartIndex; ic < lineEndIndex; ic++) {

            CGFloat startOffset = CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex(line, ic, NULL);
            _characterFrames[ic].origin = CGPointMake(startOffset, lineOrigin.y);
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Rendering Text:

-(void)renderInContext:(CGContextRef)context contextSize:(CGSize)size{

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Draw Core Text attributes string:
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, CGRectGetHeight(_frameRect));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTFrameDraw(_ctFrame, context);

    // Draw line and letter frames:
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddRects(context, _lineFrames, _lineCount);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddRects(context, _characterFrames, _attributedString.string.length);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

Comment: Do you need to work at that level? It seems like NSLayoutManager's `-boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer:` method might do the trick if you call it for each glyph and give it a range of length 1.

Comment: NSLayoutManager is available from iOS7. I want to support iOS6 at least.

Comment: Gotcha, although that becomes less important with [each passing day](http://www.maclife.com/article/news/apple_ios_7_adoption_rate_now_80).

Comment: Still, it does not mean one should stop using and trying ot understand underlaying Core Text...

Comment: I actually haven't bee able to reproduce @Lukasz results using `boundingRectForGlyphRange:inTextContainer`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764316/using-nslayoutmanager-to-calculate-frames-for-each-glyph

Comment: Was `kCTFontDefaultOrientation` changed to `kCTFontOrientationDefault`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You did an impressive amount of work in your question and were *so* close on your own. The problem you were having comes from this line of code where you position the bounding boxes for each frame:

```
_characterFrames[ic].origin = CGPointMake(startOffset, lineOrigin.y);
```

The problem with it is that you are *overriding* whatever offset the frame already had.

If you were to comment out that line you would see that all the frames were positioned *more or less* in the same place *but* you would also see that they are not positioned at the exact same place. Some are positioned more to the left or right and some more up or down. This means that the frames for the glyphs have a position of their own.

[image]

The solution to your problem is to take the current position of the frames into account when you move them into their correct place on the lines. You can either do it by adding to x and y separately:

```
_characterFrames[ic].origin.x += startOffset;
_characterFrames[ic].origin.y += lineOrigin.y;
```

or by offsetting the rectangle:

```
_characterFrames[ic] = CGRectOffset(_characterFrames[ic],
                                    startOffset, lineOrigin.y);
```

Now the bounding boxes will have their correct positions:

[image]

and you should see that it works for some of the more extreme fonts out there

[image]

Comment: Zapfino always has a melting effect in my heart! <3

Comment: @LeoNatan It's also the "did I really get it right?" of most things text related :)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist The LinoType Zapfino Extra LT (and Extra LTX) are much more interesting, for their complex scripting of ligatures. It would be interesting running that code on a heavily contextualized Zapfino Extra LTX sample. :D

Comment: How can I do the same for other glyphs then letters or numbers? This technique does not work for example for `@.#),-+` etc. as  `CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs` returns exactly following rectangle `{x: 0.6, y: 0, w: 4.8, h: 6.144}` for anything else then numbers and letters - no matter what the real dimension is.

Comment: @drasto My code from before works just fine with `@.#),-+`. However, it breaks for composed characters (⌘ etc.)

Comment: @drasto But that would depend on the font you are using. Every character that isn't supported for that font would be returned as `0` from `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` and passing that into `CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs` does (as you've seen) return the bounds for the wrong glyph.

Comment: I am using *HelveticaNeue* - all used characters should be supported. Definitelly in Swift `CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs` returns constant (thus incorrect) rectangle for everything but numbers and letters. Can you have a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27048807/311865)? There is the exact code I am using

Answer (score 1):

[image: Swift version]

Swift 5, Xcode 11:

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
   
    
       context.textMatrix = .identity
       context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height)
       context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
   
    
       let string = "｜優勝《ゆうしょう》の｜懸《か》かった｜試合《しあい》。｜Test《テスト》.\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 12354567890 @#-+"

    
       let attributedString = Utility.sharedInstance.furigana(String: string)
   
       let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: attributedString.string)

       attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)

   
       let framesetter = attributedString.framesetter()
   
       let textBounds = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
       let frame = framesetter.createFrame(textBounds)
    
//Draw the frame text:
   
       frame.draw(in: context)
           
       let origins = frame.lineOrigins()
   
       let lines = frame.lines()

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.7)

        for i in 0 ..< origins.count {

            let line = lines[i]
         
            for run in line.glyphRuns() {
            
                let font = run.font
                let glyphPositions = run.glyphPositions()
                let glyphs = run.glyphs()
            
                let glyphsBoundingRects =  font.boundingRects(of: glyphs)
            
//DRAW the bounding box for each glyph:
            
                for k in 0 ..< glyphPositions.count {
                    let point = glyphPositions[k]
                    let gRect = glyphsBoundingRects [k]
            
                    var box = gRect
                    box.origin +=  point + origins[i] + textBounds.origin
                    context.stroke(box)
                        
                }// for k
        
            }//for run
        
       }//for i
    
    }//func draw
```

Made with a CoreText Swift Wrapper.
Full Source: https://github.com/huse360/LetterFrame