# Core Text calculate letter AND ruby annotation frames in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, character, bounding-box, core-text

How can I get the bounding box for each ruby annotation character (or furigana) in a CTFrame text rendered by CoreText and CoreGraphics in iOS? (iOS 11, 12 or 13)

[image]

Based on this question [Core Text calculate letter frame in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443625/core-text-calculate-letter-frame-in-ios/63386951#63386951) I made a swift version program that encloses each character in a red box but **I wasn't able to get the bounding boxes for the ruby annotation characters**, *aka furigana*. I painted in green the ruby character boxes for the purpose of this question.

How can I achieve that? Any Ideas?

Edit: For clarity, the green boxes were painted by hand in an illustration software. I need to draw the green boxes by code.

The full source is in GitHub https://github.com/huse360/LetterFrame
This is the main source code:

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
   
    
       context.textMatrix = .identity
       context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.bounds.size.height)
       context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
   
    
       let string = "｜優勝《ゆうしょう》の｜懸《か》かった｜試合《しあい》。｜Test《テスト》.\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 12354567890 @#-+"

    
       let attributedString = Utility.sharedInstance.furigana(String: string)
   
       let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: attributedString.string)

       attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)

   
       let framesetter = attributedString.framesetter()
   
       let textBounds = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
       let frame = framesetter.createFrame(textBounds)
    
//Draw the frame text:
   
       frame.draw(in: context)
           
       let origins = frame.lineOrigins()
   
       let lines = frame.lines()

        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(0.7)

        for i in 0 ..< origins.count {

            let line = lines[i]
         
            for run in line.glyphRuns() {
            
                let font = run.font
                let glyphPositions = run.glyphPositions()
                let glyphs = run.glyphs()
            
                let glyphsBoundingRects =  font.boundingRects(of: glyphs)
            
//DRAW the bounding box for each glyph:
            
                for k in 0 ..< glyphPositions.count {
                    let point = glyphPositions[k]
                    let gRect = glyphsBoundingRects [k]
            
                    var box = gRect
                    box.origin +=  point + origins[i] + textBounds.origin
                    context.stroke(box)
                        
                }// for k
        
            }//for run
        
       }//for i
    
    }//func draw
```

Comment: How do you know that the green bounding boxes are incorrect? I mean, they might look visually incorrect, but in the font itself the glyph might have some padding.

Comment: No, the green ones were painted by hand in an illustration software, just for the purpose of this question. The red ones came from the program. I mean: I need to draw the green ones by code.

Comment: You can try to convert those glyphs to `CGPathRef`, and then find the bounding box of `CGPathRef`, like this: `let letter = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyphs[k], nil)`, `let gRect = letter.boundingBox`

Comment: I did it but the ruby annotation is missing... I can get the ruby text from the CTRun but not the screen coordinates. I appreciate if you can elaborate a bit more...

Comment: Yeah, seems like CTRun does not consider annotations as parts of the displayed glyph. Looks like the exact position and size of annotations is available only on the private API level.

Comment: It must be a way to solve this.