# How to remove default extra space or padding in UILabel without setting height constraint?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have an `UILabel` which has three constraints - `top, left and right`. It has some unnecessary space at the top and bottom. Do we've anyway to get rid of that space without setting a height constraint as I want height based on a font size? I'm attaching the image for reference. I want label text aligned with edges without any space or padding. I've tried many solutions from StackOverflow but nothing worked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That's not *"unnecessary space"* ... that's for the ascenders and descenders. If you want to clip to the **glyphs** you'll need to use Core Text and work with the glyph data.

Comment: Take a look at this q&a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443625/core-text-calculate-letter-frame-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

You should set more than `251` `huggingPriority` value for a specific `axis` for your label.

To do it

1. you should use the following method if you created label from code:

   `func setContentHuggingPriority(_ priority: UILayoutPriority,  for axis: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis)`
2. or you can set `huggingPriority` in `Interface Builder` in `Size Inspector` tab if you created label from `InterfaceBuilder`
   [image]

Comment: Already tried all these things. not working!