# How to convert 'UnsafeRawPointer?' to 'CTLine'

Tags: swift

I am ultimately trying to get per-character font metrics from a line of text.

Using `CTFramesetter` I've converted a swift `String` into lines by [following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443625/core-text-calculate-letter-frame-in-ios/21497660#21497660) (and converting from Obj-C to Swift.

The simplified code below gives me the error `Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' to expected argument type 'CTLine'` (error on `theLine`)

```
    let lines : CFArray = CTFrameGetLines(ctFrame)

    var ascent : CGFloat
    var descent : CGFloat
    var leading : CGFloat

    var theLine = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, 0)
    let lineWidth = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(theLine, &ascent, &descent, &leading) // ERROR HERE
    print("lineWidth \(lineWidth), ascent \(ascent), descent \(descent)")
```

I'm new to Swift but I've tried many things all to no avail.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just dealing with type-conversions from Core Foundation (which has very sloppy types) to Swift (which has pretty strict types).

Define `lines` this way and things will be much simpler:

```
let lines = CTFrameGetLines(ctFrame) as! [CTLine]
```

The rest of the code (with some minor fixes) would then be:

```
var ascent : CGFloat = 0
var descent : CGFloat = 0
var leading : CGFloat = 0

if let theLine = lines.first {
    let lineWidth = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(theLine, &ascent, &descent, &leading)
    print("lineWidth \(lineWidth), ascent \(ascent), descent \(descent)")
}
```

CTFrameGetLines is known to return `[CTLine]`, so `as!` is pretty safe here, but if it makes you nervous, you can use an `as?` cast like:

```
let lines = CTFrameGetLines(ctFrame) as? [CTLine] ?? []
```