How to Calculate Text width according to font (script categories font) in ios?
I was creating a feature where user can add a text and apply different font basically i have taken a Uitextview for this. what i was doing is calculating text size based on string and after getting size i am setting the frame of textview it mostly work in all the font. but while using the script categories font like Radicalis, Allura. some of the letters get cut it means the size i was getting is not correct. enter image description here
I am calculating the size of text using this
let labelSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

i am expecting to get correct size for every category font.

May be this helps you to calcualte size of the text https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904016/833395

I have already tried this one it does work for simple font but not with the script one.

Script / decorative fonts very often have character bounding boxes that extend outside the result of .sizeThatFits (and auto-layout framing by default). You will probably need to calculate the glyphs... see this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443625/core-text-calculate-letter-frame-in-ios ... it addresses drawing boxes around each character, but you could use the same rect calcs to get the sum of the widths, accounting for character offsets.

@DipeshPatel - are you still looking for a solution?

@DonMag yes, i'm still looking for solution. the answer you linked here it seems for coreText and here i'm using basic textview. i'm not sure please explain.

@DipeshPatel - you cannot use .sizeToFit() with script / decorative fonts. Try it with Zapfino at 34-point font size: https://i.sstatic.net/XWbxLvic.png

@DonMag - I need swift version of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443625/core-text-calculate-letter-frame-in-ios

@DipeshPatel - did you try the Swift code answer at that same link?

@DipeshPatel - what is your goal? you said "i'm using basic textview" ... does that mean you want to dynamically size the textView while the user edits the text in the selected font?

@DonMag  sorry for late response. I don't want to dynamically size textview while editing. I just want to fix it in textview. Just like any photo editing app. Where user can add text and according to text size the border will wrap it. I tried to use the given code in your link but I can't find the functions like attributedString.framesetter().
